# How to delete .classpath file from RTC stream?

Tags: rtc

How to delete ".classpath" file from RTC stream?

If we deleted file from local WS, it should be display in pending changes, but for .classpath file deletion, it never work

Answer (score 1):

It should work, unless you have a `.jazzignore` which already ignore the `.classpath` file.

In that case, the Pending changes view would not display anything in the unresolved section when that file is removed.

Also, if you have the project loaded in the "project explorer view", you should delete it first (choose the option to delete without removing it from the disk).

Answer (score 0):

You probably use Eclipse client. In Eclipse .classpath file is automatically generated for Java projects. Therefore, if you want to delete it, you should close your Eclipse client first.